# :first-child pseudo-class doesn't work

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a two divs with the class of `shoots`. I want the first div to have a `padding-top` of 10px and the last div to have a `padding-bottom` of 10px.

For this I am trying to use the pseudo-class selectors `:first-child` & `:last-child`.

`last-child` works, I have my padding at the bottom of the div, but the `first-child` doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

**Mark up:**

```
<div class="item-list">
     <div class='item'>
         <div class="shoots">
              *content*
         </div>
         <div class="shoots">
              *content*
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item-list .item .shoots:first-child
{
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.item-list .item .shoots:last-child
{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/gBSyh/ Need more information about your problem.

Comment: The code you've posted works as intended. Please try to extend your test case, or provide a link where the problem is prominent/

Comment: [`:first-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t17) has buggy support in IE8 and is not supported on earlier versions, and [`:last-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t35) is not supported in IE8 or below.

Comment: What `DOCTYPE` has your HTML document?

Answer (score 1):

:first-child & :last-child. don't work on block element , they only work on inline elements

Answer (score 0):

Try just doing:

```
.shoots:first-child{
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.shoots:last-child{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```